# WatiN and Google Instant

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer-10, watin

I just downloaded and built WatiN and run the sample in their site (without a couple of lines):

```
using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
{
    browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
}
```

But when run, Google won't show instant results so seems that some events are not being properly fired to really emulate a user typing. Any idea what is WatiN (or the code above) missing and how could it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

If i test your code it does exactly what you coded.

- open browser at "http://www.google.com"
- Type "WatiN" in the "q" textfield
- close the browser.

The instant results works and the typing works. what exactly is not working for you?

I would suggest not using a `using`, i know that sounds crazy but the browser closes when its disposed, also you can close it yourself.

Comment: Which version of IE do you have? I have 10.

Comment: Watin has most of the same results with IE 8, 9 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach

```
var url = "http://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr";
//Create an IE browser instance
var browser = new IE();
browser.GoTo(url);
// Wait for the browser to load properly.
browser.WaitForComplete();
//Find the Search textbox
var txtSearch = browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q"));
if (!txtSearch.Exists)
{ 
 //log error here as the elemnt with property specified is not found
}
// Assign the value (what you want to search)
txtSearch.Value = "WATIN";

// Find the search button
var btnSearch = browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")); 
if (!btnSearch.Exists)
{
//log error here as the elemnt with property specified is not found
}
//Click the search button
btnSearch.Click();

// Now you have search results so you can do whatever operations you want to perform
//When done, close the browser.
browser.Close();
```